# Problemas con treeview Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo problemas para que me imprima los datos de tabla correctamente y ordenados, imprime solo una tupla y no muestra el primer registro. cual podria ser mi error. gracias por la ayuda.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=videotk user=postgres password=1234")
conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')

class Empleado():

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('NOMINA EMPLEADOS')

        # Creating a Frame Container

        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Registre el nuevo Empleado')
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

        # Name Input
        Label(frame, text='Nombre: ').grid(row=1, column= 0, columnspan=1)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.focus()

        self.name.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Price Input

        Label(frame, text='Salario: ').grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.price = Entry(frame)
        self.price.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # Button Add Product
        ttk.Button(frame, text='Guardar Empleado').grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E)

        # Table


        self.tree = ttk.Treeview( height=10, columns=3)
        self.tree.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Nombre', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Salario', anchor=CENTER)

        self.get_empleados()

    def get_empleados (self):


        cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        cur.execute("""select * from empleado """)

        rows = [cur.fetchall()]

        for row in rows:
            self.tree.insert('', 0,  text=row[1:], values=row[2:])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Empleado(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: text=row[1:], values=row[2:] <--- logica!

Comment: Explicame por favor, la logica? por que si le quito los dos puntos, solo me muestra el segundo registro incompleto en la fila 0 columna 1

Comment: @Jsierra2017 Los dos puntos son el operador "slice" que sirve para extraer de una lista una serie de elementos. A la izquierda de los dos puntos pones en qué elemento empezar, y si no pones nada se entiende desde el primero,  y a la derecha en qué elemento terminar (terminaría en el anterior). Si no pones nada a la derecha va hasta el último.

Comment: Ok, entendi esa parte, pero el problema, es que me sigue imprimiento los datos en un solo registro, como tuplas {id1, nombre, valor }{id2, tnombre, valor].

Answer (score 1):

tienes que hacerlo asi:

```
   rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       self.tree.insert('', 0,  text=row["name"], values=row["salario"])
```

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mas porque esto soluciona el problema?

Comment: Hermano, gracias, solucionado, me sacaste de apuros. la salida de datos de tabla con sqlite3, difiere mucho con postgres. y me enrede.

Comment: sigue mostrando este error, a que se debe? alguien puede ayudarme? self.tree.insert(' ', 0, text=row["Nombre"], values=row["Precio"], values=row["Cantidad"]) ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Answer (score -1):

El error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

te loda, mas que seguro porque estas usando mal el argumento "value"... deverias pasarle una tupla a value del contenido de las columnas que declaraste en el orden que lo hiciste, seria:

```
self.tree.insert(' ', 0, text=row["Nombre"], values=(row["Precio"],row["Cantidad"]))
```

Creo que eso lo resuelve!